# use <c:forEach> to loop through element

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jpa, jstl

i tried looping through an item based on the values available on the database but my index page came out blank. please what could have cuz this.. i have values already inserted in the mysql database. but it can't appear on the index page

my index page code:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${products}">
    <jsp:useBean id="p" class="com.testing.products.Products"/>
    <div class=" col-md-6 features15-col-text">
        <div class="d-flex feature-unit align-items-center">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="features15-info">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="" alt=" ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="features15-para">
                    <h6>${p.price}</h6>
                    <h4>${p.productName}</h4>
                    <p>Ras effic itur metusga via suscipit</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success w-50 touch" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#easy" >buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

this is my servlet code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try
    {

        List<Products> products = ProductDAO.getAllProducts();

        request.setAttribute("products", products);
    }
    catch(Exception xcp)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `<c:out` ? ... it's been a very long time since I've dealt with `jsp`, but I found an example using that here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm (though it may be old info)

Comment: Have you checked to see if the servlet code is being hit at all?

Comment: The response is empty.  Do you want the servlet to forward to a different jsp or servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you're missing the import of the JSTL library.

Thus the `<c:forEach>` actually does nothing, it doesn't loop around the list, and doesn't put any value in `p`.

Adding the import should fix the issue:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:forEach var="p" items="${products}" >
    ${p.productName} - ${p.price}
</c:forEach>
```

Note that the `<jsp:useBean ...>` line is useless and should be removed.